# Dynamic Text in Lottie Animation changes its position

Tags: android, android-animation, lottie

I was wondering how to dynamically enter a text in your Lottie animations. Everything pointed me to TextDelegate.

I do have an animation and when i use text delegate, the position of the text changes with 50-60 pixels off on Y axis and 20-30 pixels on X axis.

I was wondering are there any guidelines on how to create Lottie animations that support dynamic text. I can't even find other Lottie examples that support dynamic text. So at this point I'm confused on whether is it the way the Lottie JSON I have or is it my code.

Here's a straightforward snippet:

```
 fun useTextDelegate(text: String) {
    textDelegate = TextDelegate(dynamicTextView)
    textDelegate.setText("Good Morning!", text)
    dynamicTextView.setTextDelegate(textDelegate)
    dynamicTextView.playAnimation()
}
```

Use Case: Good Morning / Good Evening / Good Night.
Depending on the time, I want to change the text.

Answer (score -2):

<sup>Solution from OP migrated from comments to an answer:</sup>

> I managed to fix this but it was kind of a hack. Usually text in your lottie file will be `"t": "Random Text`". So you update the JSON during run time. It's not perfect. `val newLottieJson = oldJson.replace("\"t\": \"Random Text!\"", "\"t\":\"${nameEditText.text}\"")`.